# Generate PRN file with unique name

Tags: command-line, printing, network-printer

The company that I worked for would like to get rid of sharing printers system and develop its own server-client system. 
Rather than sharing printers in the network, we would like to generate the prn file programmatically in the server , send prn file to client and let a process print this prn file using a local printer.

We achieved generating prn file with the following method.

In control panel

- add new printer
- the printer that I wasn’t listed
- add a local printer or network printer with manual settings
- use existing port -> FILE: (Print to file)
- Godex RT860i (as driver)
- A printer name(for example Godex-Prn-Generator)

When we create a printer using the steps above, we are able to create the prn file in Documents using C# application with running “GoLabel -f "C:\Test\123.ezpx" -i " Godex-Prn-Generator” in a command line

To get the system work, we have to know which prn file goes to which client. Here the problem is, the prn files which are created in Documents folder named as “Godex job.prn”. For this reason, we are not able to distinguish each prn file.
In order to distinguish each prn file, we should  be able to add a unique id at the beginning or at the end of the prn file.

Is there a way to generate prn files with a unique name which is set by C# application?

Comment: I hope the documents are not too complex or I guarantee you will run into troubles with graphics and fonts and different operating systems that handle print jobs differently. check for example for a third party tool like fileprocessor.info (combined with printandshare.info) instead of reinventing the wheel. These tools have also options to rename jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your command in a batch script and include a copy command that renames the Godex file.

my_golabel_script

```
SET file=%~I
GoLabel -f %file% -i " Godex-Prn-Generator
move Godex job.prn %file%.prn
```

Now you can do:

```
my_golabel_script    "C:\Test\123.ezpx"
```

Be aware that your prn file will be in the same folder as the original.

Comment: This is an excellent answer however It does not solve the race condition. If we assume  my_golabel_script is called at the same time with different processes, we never make sure which printing job will be finalized first. 

I am not too familiar with these but I assume 
when executing "GoLabel -f %file% -i " Godex-Prn-Generator" line, GoLabel creates another process.For this reason, I dont think the line
"move Godex job.prn %file%.prn" will wait for previous line to finish its job. 
Thank you for giving us this idea though

Comment: Use 'start /wait GoLabel -f %file% -i " Godex-Prn-Generator'